# Instead of C:\SQLDBA\ServerName\Instance rather C:\SQLDBA\ServerName_Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to create a folder based on the servername\instance to backup up to, i want the folder to create as servername_instance. Could you please point out where i am going wrong as it creates as servername\instance

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempPSCreateFolder') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [TempPSCreateFolder]
(QueryText nvarchar(max))
END

INSERT INTO [TempPSCreateFolder]

SELECT '$fso = new-object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject

$fso.CreateFolder("C:\'+ STUFF((SELECT ',' + SUBSTRING(@@SERVERNAME, 1, CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @@SERVERNAME) > 0 THEN 
CHARINDEX(',', @@ServerName)-1
                       ELSE LEN(@@ServerName)
                    END)

FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')+'")'

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
RECONFIGURE

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp master.dbo.TempPSCreateFolder out 
"C:\SQLDBA\CreateFolder.ps1" -c -T -SServer\Instance'

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;  
RECONFIGURE

DROP TABLE TempPSCreateFolder
```

Comment: You can utilize `sys.xp_create_subdir` to create the folder in pure T-SQL if desired as well. Since you are already running code in T-SQL there is no real reason to try and do this in PowerShell, unless you have a strict requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script seems unduly complicated. All you need to do to format the folder name according to the title of your question is replace the backslash in `@@SERVERNAME` with an underscore. No need for the table, script file, and `XML PATH` for this task. PowerShell also includes a `New-Item` command to avoid the need for the legacy COM `FileSystemObject`.

```
DECLARE @PowershellCommand varchar(8000) = 'powershell -Command "New-Item -Path \"C:\SQLDBA\'
    + REPLACE(@@SERVERNAME, '\', '_')
    + '\" -ItemType \"directory\""';
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  --assumes 'show advanced' config option is already enabled 
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @PowershellCommand;
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;  
RECONFIGURE;
```

You could also avoid `xp_cmdshell` entirely and just run a stand-alone PowerShell script on the server:

```
New-Item -Path "C:\SQLDBA\ServerName_InstanceName" -ItemType "directory"
```